# Spring XML tx:advice equivalent of @TransactionConfiguration?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, rollback, spring-aop

I'm using XML based transaction configuration in Spring 3.0.5.  Moving to annotation based is not an option.  What is the equivalent of @TransactionConfiguration( rollback=true) in XML based configuration?

At the moment, I am not enforcing rollbacks in my JUnits, so my DB is getting consistently full of random test data that must be dropped/cleaned.  Additionally, I end up having PK conflicts between different test runs.

My applicatonContext reads as follows:

```
...
<!-- Wrap all DAO Implementations in a transaction -->
<aop:config proxy-target-class="false">
    <aop:pointcut id="daoOperation" expression="execution(* com.calculator.dao.impl.*Impl.* (..))" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="daoOperation" advice-ref="txAdvice" />
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" read-only="true" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="execute*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="query*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="insert" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="delete" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="${datasource.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${datasource.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${datasource.password}" />
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
</bean>

...
```

How do I specify that I want all my JUnits to rollback by default?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Comment: @Xstian - That is a project from a long time ago.  I never ended up finding a solution to my issue directly.  I think I ended up recoding my unit tests in such a way that they never did a full commit.  Unfortunately, I don't remember much more than that, and I no longer have access to any of the sources for that project.  It is also possible that I bit the bullet and used an H2 DB instead of the Oracle db for the unit tests; I really can't remember.

Answer (score 1):

Put on your JUnit test class this configuration.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/pathTo/spring/context/applicationContext.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class LocationDaoTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{

  @Test
  public void testDAOsCRUD(){}
}
```

I hope I've given you all the answers about your question.